# Magento 2.3.2 issue after create customer mail sending in multiple website

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

> Hi,
>
> i setup multiple website with sub folder method.
>
> In First website all working fine but in second website customer email
> notification did't work and shows 500 internal server error.
>
> this issue caused in local environment.

Comment: Can you please share the error log file?

Comment: In log file nothing regarding this issue.
no any exception or warring in log files.

Comment: 500 is logged by webserver, not Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please revert your latest modification on database which could be
>   related to 'core_config','email_template' or any other email table.
>
> Hope it works